# why embedding_lookup only used as encoder but no decoder in ptb_word_ln.py

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, sample, word-embedding

I have a question about embedding_lookup while I looking the tensorflow's official sample code ptb_word_ln.py.
[the embedding_lookup node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIc00.png)

I found it is only used as an input. the output doesn't use this. so the loss evaluation cannot be benefit from this embedding. so what is the benefit using embedding_lookup here? If I want to use this word-embedding in the optimizer, shouldn't I connect it with loss function explicitly?

the source code as following:

```
self._input = input_

batch_size = input_.batch_size
num_steps = input_.num_steps
size = config.hidden_size
vocab_size = config.vocab_size

def lstm_cell():
  # With the latest TensorFlow source code (as of Mar 27, 2017),
  # the BasicLSTMCell will need a reuse parameter which is unfortunately not
  # defined in TensorFlow 1.0. To maintain backwards compatibility, we add
  # an argument check here:
  if 'reuse' in inspect.getargspec(
      tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell.__init__).args:
    return tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(
        size, forget_bias=0.0, state_is_tuple=True,
        reuse=tf.get_variable_scope().reuse)
  else:
    return tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(
        size, forget_bias=0.0, state_is_tuple=True)
attn_cell = lstm_cell
if is_training and config.keep_prob < 1:
  def attn_cell():
    return tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(
        lstm_cell(), output_keep_prob=config.keep_prob)
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(
    [attn_cell() for _ in range(config.num_layers)], state_is_tuple=True)

self._initial_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, data_type())

with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
  embedding = tf.get_variable(
      "embedding", [vocab_size, size], dtype=data_type())
  inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, input_.input_data)#only use embeddings here

if is_training and config.keep_prob < 1:
  inputs = tf.nn.dropout(inputs, config.keep_prob)

outputs = []
state = self._initial_state
with tf.variable_scope("RNN"):
  for time_step in range(num_steps):
    if time_step > 0: tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
    (cell_output, state) = cell(inputs[:, time_step, :], state)
    outputs.append(cell_output)

output = tf.reshape(tf.stack(axis=1, values=outputs), [-1, size])
softmax_w = tf.get_variable(
    "softmax_w", [size, vocab_size], dtype=data_type())
softmax_b = tf.get_variable("softmax_b", [vocab_size], dtype=data_type())
logits = tf.matmul(output, softmax_w) + softmax_b
loss = tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.sequence_loss_by_example(
    [logits],
    [tf.reshape(input_.targets, [-1])],
    [tf.ones([batch_size * num_steps], dtype=data_type())])
self._cost = cost = tf.reduce_sum(loss) / batch_size
self._final_state = state

if not is_training:
  return

self._lr = tf.Variable(0.0, trainable=False)
tvars = tf.trainable_variables()
grads, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(tf.gradients(cost, tvars),
                                  config.max_grad_norm)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self._lr)
self._train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(
    zip(grads, tvars),
    global_step=tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step())

self._new_lr = tf.placeholder(
    tf.float32, shape=[], name="new_learning_rate")
self._lr_update = tf.assign(self._lr, self._new_lr)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually output *does* use the embedding lookup.
TensorFlow programs are usually structured into a construction phase, that assembles a graph, and an execution phase that uses a session to execute ops in the graph.

In your case in order to compute loss you have to compute the following nodes on the graph in this order:

`loss -> logits -> output -> outputs -> cell -> inputs -> embedding_lookup`

Another way to look at it is if those were nested function calls:

`loss(logits(output(outputs(cell_output(cell(inputs(embedding_lookup(embedding))))))))`

I have emitted additional arguments from each function (op) to make it more clear.

Comment: Hi gidim, thanks for your reply. Emm, I'm still cannot understand why you said "output use the embedding lookup". From the code, embedding is only used by inputs. The loss function is  calculated by output * softmax_w + softmax_b which should be a one-hot loss. So I don't think the embedding is utilized by the loss result. So what is the benefit using embedding_lookup here.

Comment: the embedding is definitely utilized by the loss. See how is output computed? just follow the code. Also edited the question with another example